# Pausing .each fade loop

Tags: jquery, delay, fade, each

I have an .each loop in jquery that fades out images to reveal them in the background. Every subsequent image is assigned an increased delay. Is it possible to pause such a loop through clicking?

```
 <?php
    $ttlart = count($rows);
    echo "var ttlart = " . $ttlart . ";";
    foreach ($rows as $ro) {
        $fadedur = $ro['fadedur'];
            echo "fadedur = " . $fadedur . ";";
            $staysonscreen = $ro['staysonscreen'];
            echo "staysonscreen= " . $staysonscreen . ";";
        $order = $ro['order'];
            echo "order= " . $order. ";";
            echo "$(\"#" . $order . "\").css(\"font-size\",fadedur);";
            echo "$(\"#" . $order . "\").css(\"text-indent\",staysonscreen);";     
            //echo "alert(\"here\");";
    }
    ?>

    var artdelay = 0;
    var playstop = 0;
    var ctr = 1;    

    $($("#images img").get().reverse()).each(function(){
       fadedur = parseInt($(this).css("font-size"));
       staysonscreen = parseInt($(this).css("text-indent"));
       artdelay = artdelay+staysonscreen;

       if (ctr < ttlart){
       $(this).delay(artdelay).fadeOut(fadedur); 
        artdelay = artdelay+fadedur;

      $(".jp-controls").click(function(){

       if(playstop == 0){
       $("#images img").stop(true);
       playstop = 1;
       }else{ //alert(artdelay);
       $("#images img").delay(artdelay).fadeOut(fadedur);
       playstop = 0;}

       });

       ctr=ctr+1;}
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>You might be able to do something like this:</strike>

http://jsfiddle.net/EJ6Yg/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var delay = 200;
    $('div').each(function () {
        $(this).delay(delay).fadeOut('slow');
        delay *= 1.5;
    });
});
```

Replace `div` with some selector for your images, of course.

After reading your update, I think I see the problem - you are using `delay()` but you want to be able to pause or stop the animations.

The [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) mentions this specifically:

> The .delay() method is best for delaying between queued jQuery
>   effects. Because it is limited—it doesn't, for example, offer a way to
>   cancel the delay—.delay() is not a replacement for JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function, which may be more appropriate for certain use
>   cases.

I believe this is a use case where `setTimeout` is more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply but I forgot to specify that I need the pause to be initiated on click. That doubles the difficulty.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your help. Do you see what I am trying to do?

Comment: I basically want to put pause on my slidewhow by click. I thought it would be easy.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try it out and let you know how it goes!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I figured it out using setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm understanding your question correctly, but try something like  this.

```
$.each($).wait(1000, function(index) {
    // Sets a 1 second delay between iterations
});
```

Comment: I apologize I didn't specify that it must be done by clicking. Thank both of you for your help either way.